# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre asmx y wsdl?

Tags: webservice, wsdl, .asmx

estoy aprendiendo a consumir web service, pero no entiendo por que la url para consumirlo tiene que tener extensión url/Ws.asmx y para acceder a la descripción url/Ws.asmx?WSDL, sí mi web service tiene la extensión .wsdl, ademas qué después de subirlo al hosting y buscarlo con la extencion url/Ws.asmx?WSDL genera error 404, como si este no existiera, y no encuentro documentación al respecto por ningún foro. Se que debe parecer una pregunta absurda, pero estoy confundido y no logro comprender por que debería usar esa extensión url/Ws.asmx?WSDL.

Comment: Accede a .wsdl drectamente.

Comment: WSDL es la descripcion de tu servicio digamos como documentacion. asmx es el recurso que consumes, como ambos contiened la definicion del servicio son muy parecidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSDL es el estándar SOAP para los contratos. Siempre se va a definir un archivo WSDL (un XML con una estructura dada)

Otra cosa es cómo tu framework expone el contrato del web service. Puede serializar un .WSDL, puede poner un endpoint (como CXF) `http://website/webservices` y otros, como tu framework, ponen un archivo .asmx con el mismo contenido XML que configura tu contrato WSDL.